# Tenses in zero conditional

Tags: grammar, conditionals

I'm wondering about contradictions in zero-conditional explanation in different sources.

[Some of them](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/zero-conditional.html) state that **only** Present simple + present simple is correct.

[Some of them](http://www.grammaring.com/zero-conditional) state that present and past simple are correct till both sides have the same tense.

[And some of them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_conditional) state that all simple tenses (present + past + futute) are correcnt till both sides have the same tense.

Which source is right (for American English)? And if I can use past and/or future - what the difference between all of them?

Comment: What’s a “zero conditional”? Native speakers are not taught such simplifications, I’m afraid, so we don’t know what you are asking. Also, it gets really confusing when you talk about tenses and conditionals. If it were a tense, we would have told you so. :)

Comment: I implore you to abandon the pointless n-conditional classification. The names are uninformative, and the categories do not reflect any linguistic or logical reality. The classification is a pedagogical device which in the end only confuses learners.

Comment: @StoneyB I don't like it too but it appears in almost every (incl. Oxford's ones) book for English learners.

Comment: @tchrist you can find explanation of what "zero conditional" means from links in the question. I'm sorry but I don't know how to explain it better, I'm just trying to understand it.

Comment: @Oxilumin. You are right that pedagogic grammars commonly categorize conditional constructions by the numbers 0-3 (although the better grammars warn that this is a considerable simplification of real language usage). And you are also right that the sources you cite are contradictory in their definiton of the zero conditional. All this suggests that you are better off studying the most common patterns without worrying about how they are sometimes designated.

Comment: A more descriptive designation of the four patterns is given by Yule in _Explaining English Grammar_. He categorizes conditional forms as _Factual, Predictive, Hypothetical, and Counterfactual_. These can be considered roughly equivalent to the 0-3 conditionals.

Comment: @oxilumin There was a time when the theory of Humours appeared in every book for medical students.

Comment: @tchrist Unhappily, native speakers are mostly not taught anything at all about our language.

Comment: @Shoe Given by Yule?  You mean they’re taught before Christmas? :)

Comment: If you want to learn about conditionals in today's standard English, I'd suggest you find a grammar source that uses the terms "open conditional" and "remote conditional". The involved time spheres (present time vs past time vs future time) are quite secondary to this issue. What is relevant is how the preterite (past-tense verbs) are being used: are they being used to indicate modal remoteness, or are they being used to indicate a past-time sphere (or are they being used in a backshift).

Comment: @oxilumin: You're welcome. :) If you want a readable, vetted grammar source, I'd like to suggest that you find a copy of the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL). They cover this topic in depth in Chapter 12 "The clause: adjuncts", within section 14 "Conditional adjuncts and conditional constructions", pages 738-765 (pg 738-755). If your library doesn't have it, then you might be able to google some decent info on the internet, but remember to search for those two terms ("open"/"remote" conditional constructions).

Comment: [“It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.”](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf) —from ***“If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals”,*** Christian Jones and Daniel Waller, *ELT Journal* 65:1 pp 24–32 (2011), Oxford University Press,  doi: 10.1093/elt/ccp101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were originally ***only three*** conditionals in the classification. There are a bunch of valid conditional statements not covered by these, so a number of people added a "zero conditional". Unfortunately, it seems they didn't agree on the definition of "zero conditional" before they added it to the list, so there is no "official" definition. The linked sentences are ***all*** valid English grammatical constructs, and there are even more valid conditional statements, as well. Native English speakers generally don't know or use this numbering system.

Here's how the past and present zero conditional work.

Present tense: used for a conditional statement that is generally true. This is related to the use of the present tense for habitual statements.

> If you go to school without shoes, you are sent home.

Past tense: used for a conditional statement that used to be generally true.

> If you went to school without a skirt, you were sent home.

(Note this in this case, it is no longer generally true, but it can be used for something which is still true when you're talking about the past.)

The one example of future tense zero conditional in your links doesn't have this meaning, so maybe it shouldn't be classified as a zero conditional. The tenses used for generally true future conditional statements are:

> In 2100, if you go to school without a jetpack, you will be sent home.

Comment: Thanks. If you know a good book which covers conditional statements - please send me the name.

Comment: To understand conditional statements you have to [understand logic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) and also [understand modality](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf), since what are called "conditional statements" are actually clauses involving modality of one type or another. A very good book on the latter subject is F.R. Palmer's _Mood and Modality_, in the Cambridge Textbooks series.